# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Ranking/Auto Increment

Tags: reporting-services, report, increment, builder

I want to auto increment or show a row number.
Something like

```
Rank Countries
1    America
2    Japan
3    Philippines
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new column into tablix and write textbox expression like -

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Countries.Value, CountDistinct, "DSCountry")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i found a work around by creating another dataset :D, but your answer will help me with another problem thanks!